# Web API Service Fabric app gives unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I have created a web api hosted in service fabric. When I hit the api from client it works fine on local but is giving **401** from remote machine. I have used **IntegratedWindowsAuthentication** and **Negotiate authentication schemes** in  Web API.

Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the remote machine doesn't know about the windows account on your client so it throws a 401. Try creating an account on the remote machine with the same username and password and try again.

Comment: The account is same on client and server. Then also same issue. I tried adding <SecurityAccessPolicy> in ApplicationManifest file but same issue.

Comment: They need to know about each other, that's why this only works on a Domain. Unless you set up a domain, it won't work.

Comment: I am on a Domain and using the same username on the client and server. Still struggling..

Comment: Are you sure it's not an authorization issue? Explain more how your application works so I can help you more.

Comment: I have a web API which is hosted in Service Fabric which uses **IntegratedWindowsAuthentication**. When the client is on the same machine as the service fabric cluster, it works fine.
If the client is present on some remote machine using my credentials it gives 401.
I tried looking into some policies but none were helpful.
If such a case occurs in IIS, we can change permission in application pool. But here I am not able to see what to do!

Comment: Try looking at the HTTP response for more information then I guess

Comment: Wait a second, on closer inspection, you are hosting on service fabric which means that it is not on your domain which means that the credentials won't work as per my original answer.

Comment: If I am using PostMan to post to the API on remote machine, it is working fine.

Comment: Check the request that your client is sending. Maybe there is a header or something that isn't right.

Comment: The port was not opened to allow incoming requests. But I don't know why it gave Unauthorized in place of NotFound

Comment: @Manas Singhal it gave not authorised because from the firewalls POV the client was not authorized to send data to that port.